# .NET partial class' accessibility over multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes

If I have the core of a class defined in one file as "public partial" and I wish to create additions to this in another file, what is the difference between defining "public partial" again in my second file or just defining "partial"?

What happens if I define "private partial" in my second file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can duplicate the class modifiers or leave them out in one file, but you'll get a compiler error if they're specified in different files as different access levels.

From [The C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx):

> The following keywords on a partial-type definition are optional, but if present on one partial-type definition, cannot conflict with the keywords specified on another partial definition for the same type:
>
> - public
> - private
> - protected
> - internal
> - abstract
> - sealed
> - base class
> - new modifier (nested parts)
> - generic constraints